# Are quantum physics applying to microscopic objects?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Are quantum physics applying to low massed objects or tiny objects? For example, fotons can do quantum tunneling? Are we locating thus objects that arent really there?

Comment: Can you expand (I would suggest completely reframe) what you mean by "Are we locating thus objects that arent really there?"?

Comment: proper spelling and syntax would also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have heard very often that Quantum mechanics apply to a microscopic domain. It applies to electrons, atoms, things of atomic size.
This is partially true, In reality, It applies to everything, Human beings, Earth, the Universe, etc. But it just so happen that the manifestation of
quantum mechanics becomes very dramatic when it comes to microscopic objects. It a much more dramatic when we look at microscopic
objects which are moving very fast. So that’s the reason one feels
that quantum mechanics applies to the microscopic domain which is not
true. It has some manifestations even in macroscopic objects, for example, The fact that solid are rigid objects.

The fact that one doesn’t
go through the floor when standing on it. It’s because famous Pauli exclusion principle which follows from quantum mechanics. The
phenomena like Magnetism, Propagation of sound through solid or
conduction of electricity, these are all quantum mechanical phenomena. Not just Superconductivity which is usually given as quantum
mechanical phenomena but ordinary phenomena like electrical conductivity, diamagnetism, paramagnetism, etc depend on quantum
Mechanics. They can’t be explained classically. Initially, People have
discovered these phenomena like Black-body radiation where classical mechanics fails, As we know Black-body radiation is the study of
the collection of photons and it must be treated quantum mechanically.

Comment: Yeah but would it be applied to a big object with no mass?

Comment: "It a much more dramatic when we look at microscopic objects which are moving very fast." -- This is not true. Putting aside the fact that quantum mechanical objects don't really have a well-defined speed, whether or not $E>>m$ or not (which would translate to high-speed or not in classical mechanics) corresponds to relativistic effects, not to quantum mechanical ones.

Comment: @StewartBell Yes, as far as we know it applies to every object, small, big, heavy or light. I find it difficult to imagine a big object with no mass, maybe a large ball of photons will do? Or better, an electromagnetic wave? It surely does behave according to quantum mechanics